# Как поставить 2 декоратора сразу в Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Мне нужно использовать декораторы @csrf_exempt и @api_view одновременно для одной функции. Как я могу это сделать? Сделал так:

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def messages_single(request, page = None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        messages = Message.objects.order_by('id')
        if page != None:
            try:
                messages = messages[page - 1]
            except IndexError:
                messages = {}
            finally:
                message_serializer = MessageSerializer(messages, many = False)         
        else:
            message_serializer = MessageSerializer(messages, many = True)
        return JsonResponse(message_serializer.data, safe = False)
    
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        messages_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        message_serializer = MessageSerializer(data = messages_data)
        if message_serializer.is_valid():
            message_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(message_serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return JsonResponse(message_serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

И до поры до времени это работало... Теперь же ловлю ошибку `"detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."` при попытке отправить POST запрос.

Edit. Лювлю ошибку даже с этим декоратором. Есть ли ещё какая-то причина в этом, кроме декоратора?

Comment: А если поменять порядок?

Comment: @ZaArs Пробовал, не проканало